# jQuery ui animation problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a menu with some buttons (anchors).
I want that when a certain button is pressed- a div element will appear in a slide animation.
I also want that when the user hovers over the other button- the div element will hide itself in an animation.
The problem is- if I move the mouse quickly over the other elements- the hide animation repeats itself a number of times.
Here's the code:
Javascript/jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#shiurButton").click(function(event) {
    //Shows the div element
        $(".shiurPicker").toggle('slide', {direction:'right'}, 1000);
    });

    $("#testButton").mouseover(function(event){
        if ($(".shiurPicker").is(":visible")){
            $(".shiurPicker").hide('slide', {direction:'right'}, 1000);
        }
    });

     $("#dictionaryButton").mouseover(function(event) {
        if ($(".shiurPicker").is(":visible")){
            $(".shiurPicker").hide('slide', {direction:'right'}, 1000);
        }
    });

     $("#helpButton").mouseover(function(event) {
       if ($(".shiurPicker").is(":visible")){
           $(".shiurPicker").hide('slide', {direction:'right'}, 1000);
       }
});

});
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first, combine the animations that do the same thing. then add a stop() to the animations:

```
$("#shiurButton").click(function(event) {
    //Shows the div element
    $(".shiurPicker").stop(true, true).toggle('slide', {direction:'right'}, 1000);
});

$("#testButton, #dictionaryButton, #helpButton").mouseover(function(event){
    if ($(".shiurPicker").is(":visible")){
        $(".shiurPicker").stop(true, true).hide('slide', {direction:'right'}, 1000);
    }
});
```

---

UPDATE:

Use `data()`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#shiurButton").click(function(event) {
        $(".shiurPicker").stop(true, true).show('slide', {
            direction: 'right'
        }, 1000);
        $(".shiurPicker").data('hide', false);
    });

    $("#testButton, #dictionaryButton, #helpButton").mouseover(function(event) {
        var hide = $(".shiurPicker").data('hide');
        if(hide == false){
            $(".shiurPicker").stop(true, true).hide('slide', {
                direction: 'right'
            }, 1000);
            $(".shiurPicker").data('hide', true);
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/UW9gf/

Comment: @amitairos -- try using `animate` instead of `hide` or `toggle`

Comment: @amitairos, few mintes ill make a demo

Comment: @amitairos, what exactly do u want to do?

Comment: @Neal I want to show the div in a slide to the left animation when clicking on #shiurButton,and hiding it with a slide to the right animation when clicking on the other buttons

Comment: @amitairos -- can you show me on http://jsfiddle.net a demo of what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Neal- sure, here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ay3bZ/ Click on the first button, then move the mouse quickly down on all the buttons and you'll see the error.

Comment: @Neal- awesome, thanks. It's for a web application I'm building for teaching lessons. Any tips on how to manage the content of the lessons?

Comment: @amitairos. if you need any extra help just goto my website http://blipit.net -- ill be glad to help :-)